# Save card id to model on form submission

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I want to save the stripe payment method id to my order when it's created for recurring orders.

When using a previously saved card, it works as intended saving a "card_idxxxxx" which references a stripe payment method.

Currently if the new card is input, it saves as "add-new-card", which is wrong. I would like it to save the newly input card to the customer, and also to the payment method field.

What I'm mostly unsure about is:

1. Why my card isn't saving to the customer in stripe
2. How can I pass the new card's id to my view?

template

```
<div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment-methods" id="add-new-card"
                    value="add-new-card" onclick="addCard()">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="add-new-card">
                    Add new payment method
                </label>

                <div id="new-card" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs mb-2" for="cardholder-name">
                        Name on Card
                    </label>
                    <input id="cardholder-name"
                        class="mb-2 border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                        value="{{customer.name}}" detype="text">
                    <!-- placeholder for Elements -->
                    <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs  mb-2" for="card-element">
                        Card Details
                    </label>
                    <div id="card-element"
                        class="mb-2 border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="card-result"></div>
                    <div id="card-errors" class="my-2" role="alert"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if saved_customer %}
            {% for method in payment_methods %}
            <div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment-methods" id="{{method.card}}"
                    value="{{method.id}}" onclick="hideCard()">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{method.card}}">
                    {{method.card.brand}} ending in {{method.card.last4}}
                </label>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}
```

js

```
<script>

    function addCard() {
        document.getElementById('new-card').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideCard() {
        document.getElementById('new-card').style.display = 'none';
    }
    // Stripe code
    var stripe = Stripe('{{STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}}');

    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var cardElement = elements.create('card');
    cardElement.mount('#card-element');

    var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
    var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    var resultContainer = document.getElementById('card-result');

    cardButton.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {

        stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
            billing_details: {
                name: cardholderName.value,
            },
        }
        ).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Display error.message in your UI
                resultContainer.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                // You have successfully created a new PaymentMethod
                resultContainer.textContent = "Created payment method: " + result.paymentMethod.id;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

view

````
def subscription_new(request, product):
    stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    title = "New Subscription for " + product
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(customer=customer)
    current_day = datetime.date.today().day
    # maintain order day in short months
    if current_day > 28:
        current_day = 1
    
    context = {
        'title' : title,
        'product' : product,
        'customer' : customer,
        'addresses' : addresses,
        'current_day' : current_day,
        'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY' : STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    }

            
    if customer.stripe_id:
        context['payment_methods'] = stripe.PaymentMethod.list(
                customer=customer.stripe_id,
                type="card",
            )
        context['saved_customer'] = True
        card = request.POST.get('payment-methods')
        if card == "add-new-card":
            intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(customer=customer.stripe_id)
        else:
            subscription = Subscription.objects.create(customer=customer, product=product, address=address, renewal_day=current_day, payment_method=card)
    else:
        print("create stripe id")            

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressForm(request.POST)
        address = request.POST.get('addresses')
        if address == 'new-address':
            address = form.save(commit=False)
            address.customer = customer
            address.save()
        else:
            address = Address.objects.get(id=address)
        
       
    else:
        form = AddressForm()
    context['form'] = form
   
    return render(request, 'accounts/subscription_new.html', context)    ```
````

Comment: `result.paymentMethod.id` is the PaymentMethod ID of your newly created card. Your code needs to send that to your server. Right now (from what I can tell), your form-check-input named `payment-methods` is sending its value to your backend code, which is set to value="add-new-card" which is why you're getting that in your server-side code. You need to send `result.paymentMethod.id` to your backend code.

Comment: That's one of the parts I'm confused about, how to pass that into the backend

Comment: how are you currently passing anything to your backend? like how is your Python code's `subscription_new()` function being triggered? Is it on HTML form submission?

Comment: Currently, the backend retrieves the value using this line `card = request.POST.get('payment-methods')`. It takes the value from any of the 'payment-methods' radio buttons. What I don't know, is how to pass the result data to the view

Comment: I'm making the assumption that result.paymentMethod.id is created on form submission, so not able to be passed in the same way as the existing payment methods? And also the function is triggered on page load, with an if statement that triggers on submission. I edited my question to reflect the full view function

Comment: I would recommend learning out how to post data from your webpage to your server. Really, what it comes down to is, when your `createPaymentMethod()` function resolves with a result (i.e. a PaymentMethod), you need to embed that ID in the value of your `payment-methods` radio button so that the form posts it to your server, your server is already looking up the value sent there, just that it is hardcoded to `add-new-card`.

Comment: As far as I worked out so far, this is not actually the way to do it. Instead it looks like I have to use SetupIntent and then retrieve the card from the customer afterwards. I'll try and update more concisely once I have time